# page not indexed - duplicate without user selected canonical

Tags: canonical-url

I have submitted sitemap to google and it keeps identifying unique product pages as duplicates. Can someone please explain why its happening and how to resolve them please.

All the product pages are generated dynamically. below is a sample example

Original URL: https://www.example.com/ProductDetails/barcode/9780008294816

Google-selected canonical: https://www.example.com/ProductDetails/barcode/9780008276324

The last part represents the ISBN of the books. Both are different titles but google thinks they are same.

Comment: the last part represents the ISBN of the books. Both are different titles but google thinks they are same.

Answer (score 1):

Google thinks that the contents are very similar - this includes the url, title, description and the actual contents.  Try making some changes to make them more different.

> If you have a single page accessible by multiple URLs, or different pages with similar content (for example, a page with both a mobile and a desktop version), Google sees these as duplicate versions of the same page. Google will choose one URL as the canonical version and crawl that, and all other URLs will be considered duplicate URLs and crawled less often.

Source: https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/139066?hl=en

---

- It may help to ensure that each page has a `canonical` tag point to itself.
- There are sites that will check your pages and tell you about duplicate content.  This will confirm to you what Google thinks is true or not.
- Ensure each page has a different title and description
- Ensure that each page has different images with different `title` attributes

Comment: I had the same problem. Even if the pages were quite different. I had to add canonical tag point to itself and I solve it